# Create a 2D histogram matrix (R)

Tags: r, matrix, 2d, histogram

I have two feature vectors, v1 has a car's MPG and v2 has a car's age.  They are ordered to represent a car (v1[1], v2[1] is the first car's data).

I've created 4 bins for each feature vector (and created shadow vectors wherein their bin value is shown instead of the raw number), and want to create a 2D histogram matrix for it.

So it should count the number of all the combinations that occur, and place that count in the appropriate matrix cell (ex. if there are 20 cars in the list that fit into the 2nd bin of MPG and 3rd bin of age, it'll put a 20 into matrix[2,3]).

My goal is to be able to paste this histogram into Excel.

This seems like a situation for looping, which I'm not yet familiar with in R (it was advertised to me that you don't need to use loops in R often).  I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Just use `table(b1,b2)` where `b1` and `b2` are the vectors of binned values.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how I missed this function in my googling.  Thank you, I will give it a shot.  Is there a way to upvote your reply?